# How to split large Parquet file using Apache Beam / Google Dataflow Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I need to split 30GB Parquet file with Apache Beam / Google Dataflow.
Here is the code:

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        (
            p 
            | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet("gs://my-bucket/input/my-file.parquet")
            | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToParquet(
                file_path_prefix="gs://my-bucket/output/",
                schema=SCHEMA,
                codec='snappy',
                file_name_suffix='.parquet',
                num_shards=20,
            )
         )
```

When I run this code on a small Parquet file, it runs fine. But when I run it on a big file (30GB Parquet) it sticks and throws an error after some idle time:

```
Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.
```

I tried to run it on more powerful virtual machines, as recommended [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#worker-lost-contact):

```
--worker_machine_type=e2-standard-2 --disk_size_gb=500
```

But this time the job sticks on the same step and freezes forever:

[image]

I'm not an experienced Apache Beam and Dataflow user and have not been using it for a long time. Appreciate any help.

Comment: FWIW, e2-standard-2 isn't a very powerful machine. This should still work though. Are there any interesting worker logs? Can you try without the write (e.g. just counting the number of elements) and see if that works? What about ReadFromParquetBatched?

Comment: hi, yes, you're right, it's a not very powerful machine, but it should not be the reason for the job freeze.
I think there's nothing to show in logs because logging stops when the job freezes. But I need to check again.
I'm going to try other things you suggest (e.g. just reading or ReadFromParquetBatched)